# Are all 4-manifolds $Pin^{\tilde{c}}$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, 4-manifolds

It's known that all oriented 4-manifolds admit a $Spin^c$ structure, ie. a spin structure on $TX\oplus\mathcal{L}$ for some complex line bundle $\mathcal{L}$.

A usual generalization of this structure to unorientable manifolds is to ask for a spin structure on $TX\oplus\mathcal{L}\oplus\mathcal{E}$ where $\mathcal{L}$ is again a complex line and now $\mathcal{E}$ is a real line bundle (which the whole bundle being oriented will force to be the orientation line). This is called a $Pin^c$ structure. In cohomology, it amounts to an integral lift of $w_2$.

Unfortunately, not all 4-manifolds admit a $pin^c$ structure, eg. $\mathbb{RP}^2 \times \mathbb{RP}^2$. This is easy to see by a computation of $w_2$.

There is another generalization I'll call a $Pin^{\tilde c}$ structure. In this version, $\mathcal{L}$ and $\mathcal{E}$ combine into a real 2-plane bundle. In cohomology it amounts to a *twisted* integral lift of $w_2$.

So, do all 4-manifolds admit a twisted integral lift of $w_2$?

Here are some edits in response to Qiaochu's comment. An integral lift of $w_2$ is an element of $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ mapping to $w_2$ in $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z}/2)$. A twisted integral lift lives instead in $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z}^{w_1})$, with local coefficients in the orientation line.

Comment: I can't extract from either of your descriptions what you mean by this. How does a complex line bundle and a real line bundle "combine into a real 2-plane bundle," and/or what is a twisted integral lift of $w_2$? (What is the twist, and what is it twisting?)

Comment: I've problems as well to follow your description. Could you describe the group $Pin^{\tilde c}$, please? As for $Pin^c$-structures, I guess that restricting the $Pin^c$ action to a $Spin^c$ action, you recover a $Pin^c$ structure on the orientation covering of $X$. Is this correct?

Comment: A $Pin^c$ structure is an equivariant $Spin^c$ structure on the orientation double cover, while a $Pin^{\tilde c}$ structure is a twisted equivariant $Spin^c$ structure there. (The Chern class flips sign between the two sheets.)

Comment: I believe one can think of $Pin^c(n)$ as the group $Spin(n) \times Pin^+(2)/\mathbb{Z}/2$ while $Pin^{\tilde c}$ is $Spin(n) \times Pin^-(2)/\mathbb{Z}/2$.

Comment: I am guessing that you mean that your structure is the same as a spin structure on $TX \oplus \mathcal{V}$ where $\mathcal{V}$ is a real 2-plane bundle. The obstruction for this is the existence of an integral lift of $w_2 + w_1^2$ (is this your "twisted integral lift" of $w_2$?). Doesn't $\mathbb{RP}^2 \times \mathbb{RP}^2$ give a counter-example?

Comment: No that's not correct. $w_1^2$ always admits an integral lift so your structure is the same as $Pin^c$. The point of $Pin^{\tilde c}$ is the lift lives in twisted cohomology.

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake (I momentarily forgot that the Euler class of a non-orientable bundle lives in twisted cohomology...). So $w_2 + w_1^2$ must be the mod 2 reduction of a class in twisted cohomology. Then I think that $X =\mathbb{RP}^4$ provides a counter-example. If I did my back of the envelope calculations right (please check) then $w(TX) =  1 + x + x^4$ and so $w_2 + w_1^2 = x^2$ is non-trivial, but I think $H^2(X, \mathbb{Z}^{w_1}) = 0$, so this class can't be the reduction of a twisted cohomology class.

Comment: Actually on RP4 w2 is exact...

Comment: I think maybe the argument here http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/teichner/Papers/spin.pdf can be adapted to prove the result in the positive. I'm not sure how to use universal coefficients in this twisted case though.

Comment: Oh you're looking at a third structure actually. I'm looking for a twisted integral lift of $w_2$, not $w_2+w_1^2$. These are inequivalent in the twisted case.

Comment: Okay so I remembered how universal coefficients is just something about $Ext^2$ vanishing in abelian groups, so the theorem works the same for twisted coefficients using a different chain complex. So one needs to show that the induced map $\int w_2 \in Hom(H_2(X,\mathbb{Z}^{w_1}),\mathbb{Z}/2)$ is in the image of the natural map from $Hom(H_2(X,\mathbb{Z}^{w_1}),\mathbb{Z})$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\newcommand{\RP}{\mathbb{RP}}\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}$No, $\RP^2\times\RP^2$ isn't pin<sup>$\tilde c$</sup>. This came up while thinking about [another MathOverflow
question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/310373/97265), but I'll rewrite the argument here.

What you call a pin<sup>$\tilde c$</sup>-structure has been studied in physics, following
[Metlitski](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.05663) and [Freed-Hopkins](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.06527), where it's
also called a pin<sup>$\tilde c+$</sup>-structure.  (This is because one can also ask about pin<sup>$\tilde
c-$</sup>-structures, which are twisted integral lifts of $w_2 + w_1^2$.) These structures are discussed in
a little more detail by [Shiozaki-Shapourian-Gomi-Ryu](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.01886) in Appendix D.

Here's the argument for $\RP^2\times\RP^2$: let $x$ denote the generator of $H^1(-;\Z/2)$ of the first $\RP^2$ and
$y$ be that for the second $\RP^2$. Using the usual CW structure on $\RP^2$ and the product CW strucure on
$\RP^2\times\RP^2$, you can check that $H_2(\RP^2\times\RP^2;\Z)\cong\Z/2$ and the reduction mod 2 map
$H_2(\RP^2\times\RP^2;\Z)\to H_2(\RP^2\times\RP^2;\Z/2)$ sends the nonzero element of $H_2(\RP^2\times\RP^2;\Z)$ to
the Poincaré dual of $x+y$.

The Poincaré duality isomorphisms $H_2(\RP^2\times\RP^2;\Z)\cong H^2(\RP^2\times\RP^2;\Z_{w_1})$ and
$H_2(\RP^2\times\RP^2;\Z/2)\cong H^2(\RP^2\times\RP^2;\Z/2)$ are natural with respect to change-of-coefficients,
which means that the reduction mod 2 map $\rho_2\colon H^2(\RP^2\times\RP^2;\Z_{w_1})\to
H^2(\RP^2\times\RP^2;\Z/2)$ sends the nonzero element of $H^2(\RP^2\times\RP^2;\Z_{w_1})\cong\Z/2$ to $x+y$.
However, $w_2(\RP^2\times\RP^2) = x^2+xy+y^2$, so it's not in the image of $\rho_2$, and therefore
$\RP^2\times\RP^2$ has no pin<sup>$\tilde c+$</sup>-structure.

Comment: Thanks, Arun! Indeed it seems @wonderich and I are thinking about the same things :)